# Own instance of Num with a String Datatype

Tags: haskell

I want to turn my Dataconstructor `MP` into an instance of `Num`

`MP` looks like this `data MP = MP String`
and the string is build only of + and - e.g. "++-+-+"
where every + represents a +1 and a - represents -1.

I also have already a function that normalize that string e.g. "++-+-+" to "++"

```
nrm "" = ""
nrm (c:t) = take c (nrm t)
  where
    take c "" = [c]
    take c (s:xs)
      | c == s     = c:s:xs
      | otherwise  = xs
```

And now I would like to turn this into an instance of Num like this:

```
instance Num MP where
  (+) = undefined
  (*) = undefined
  negate = undefined
  signum = undefined
  abs = undefined
  fromInteger = undefined
```

So at the End it should work like this `"+++" + "-" = "++"` or `"+++" * "-" = "---"` and so on.

Does someone have an Idea how I could do this?

Comment: Can you send your normalization function? Also what have you tried?

Comment: I have tried something like (+) (MP a)  (MP b) = (a++b) @Aplet123

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You say:

> I have tried `(+) (MP a) (MP b) = (a++b)`

You are correctly writing a function that accepts values of type `MP`, but you must also return a value of type `MP`, as in `(+) (MP a) (MP b) = MP (a ++ b)`. There are still bugs in that implementation, of course, but that should get you over the first hump and on to something you can play with further yourself.

Comment: Thank you a lot! @Daniel Wagner